# Sql script with Transaction/Rollback with "Go" statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I create desktop application. with user have select .sql file and run it with Transaction/Rollback.

in that case i read all context from sql file. and put between following code to replace sql file script with *****$Replace$***** text.

How can i handle transaction/Rollback if sql file contain "GO" batch. its throwing error.

any solution to Handel thhis type of scenario to any sql file convert to Transaction/Rollback .

Note: without changes in sql file script.

---

sql file script:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[User] ([Name]  ,[ContectNo])  VALUES ('m3','33')
    GO BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[User] ([Name]  ,[ContectNo])  VALUES ('m3',null)
    GO BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[User] ([Name]  ,[ContectNo])  VALUES ('m3','99')
    GO
-----------------------------------------------------
Transaction block: replace sql file query from *****$Replace$*****
-----------------------------------------------------


SET XACT_ABORT ON;  
GO    
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

       *****$Replace$*****

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH  

      IF @@ERROR > 0
     BEGIN
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

          DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(max) = ERROR_MESSAGE()
          DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY()
          DECLARE @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE()
          DECLARE @ErrorLine INT = ERROR_LINE()

          RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage,
                       @ErrorSeverity,
                       @ErrorState 
                      );  
     END
END CATCH
SET XACT_ABORT OFF
```

Comment: Remove "BEGIN TRANSACTION"  text from sql file script just Insert and Go statement

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error, because `GO` is not a command that should be sent to the SQL Server engine. It is something recognized by tools like SSMS, sqlcmd and osql. It signals the end of the batch of T-SQL statements and serves as a signal that the commands so far (the current batch) should be send to the SQL Server engine.

You should not try to execute `GO` statements as T-SQL. You should either try to parse the file for `GO` lines, split it into separate batches and execute them one by one, or to make sure you are passing valid T-SQL contents in these files.

You can see more information about `GO` statement in [SQL Server Utilities Statements - GO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-2017) article.

Comment: If you're wanting to mimic the client tools, you have to do a bit of parsing - `GO` shouldn't be interpreted as a batch separator when it appears inside comments or string literals. Since these can both span multiple lines, you can't necessarily rely on "first text on the line is `GO`" either. (Of course, anyone producing scripts that contain such sequences is a *very bad person* but it's legal)